# How to select QWidget by class

Tags: css, qt, selector, qwidget

Imagine, that I want to set a css style to some QWidgets in MainWindow, for example:

```
QPushButton {
    background: rgb(79, 79, 79);
}
```

But it applies css style to all QPushButtons, I would like to set background only to some QPushButtons identified by some class. How to do it?

**Edit:**

```
        <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Minimum" vsizetype="Fixed">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>0</width>
           <height>60</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>Label</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
```

Comment: Selecting buttons by class is not useful at all, since the concept of a class (as applicable to DOM elements) doesn't exist in Qt.

Comment: Im looking for something how can I select some QWidgets from others.

Comment: Great. Then don't presuppose the existence of a particular answer. Don't use the word "class" since it has a meaning you don't intend here.

Comment: And what is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to use class selector

> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp

```
QPushButton.someClass{
     background: rgb(79, 79, 79);
}
```

html will be e.g.

```
<QPushButton class='someClass'>
    Label
</QPushButton>
```

Comment: Thanks, because I cannot edit a class in Qt Designer, so do I have to edit it manually (like text) in *.ui?

Comment: you might need to ask another question for that, I'm not familiar with qt/qwidget syntax

Comment: Please you wrote that it should be <QPushButton class='someClass'>, but look at my syntax (I edited my post) I don't have a <QPushButton> but <widget>

Comment: @tomsk I dont think you need to modify existing question, as it makes answers irrelevant. you might want to create new question instead. in current case I would use `.QPushButton[name=pushButton_2]{ ... }` but it is better to add new `class` or  `id` instead e.g. `<widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2 id='button2">` and css will be` #button2.QPushButton{...}` . of course I assume you're able to iterate and create different names/ids/classes

Answer (score 1):

In your example class is `QPushButton` so your selector is right. You can use object name in selector

```
QPushButton#pushButton_2 { ... }
```

Or if you need few buttons to be styled you can use property selector

```
QPushButton[fancy=true] { ... }
```

You can add `fancy` property using QtDesigner or from code using `QObject::setProperty()`.

For more information please check documentation [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-syntax.html)